# Section label as Html treated as plain text

Tags: orbeon

I have tried to put a section label as HTML.

Here is the config of section:
[image: Section Config]

When I apply changes, this what appears on builder.
[image: Html on builder]

And then when I execute it on runner this is the result:
[image: Html on runner]

It is scaping HTML and by that is being treated as plain text.

I am using Orbeon 2018.1.2.201810050007 PE.

Maybe I am not taking in account something or missing any configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Orbeon Forms 2018.2.3 and Orbeon Forms 2019.1. See [#3671](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3671) for details. There is no backport of this fix to the Orbeon Forms 2018.1 series as of yet but if you have commercial support, please contact Orbeon directly about this.

Comment: Confirmed that after upgrade to Orbeon Forms 2018.2.3 the problem is solved and HTML is rendered properly.